# How to check if query and function are executed successfully?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I have function that takes few arguments then query delete will be executed. Right after that I call another function that will update table with time stamp and user id. The code that I use looks like this:

```
remote function deleteComment(required string storeID, required string recID) returnFormat="JSON" {
    local.fnResults = structNew();
    local.runProcess = true;

    try {
        if ( !len(arguments.recID) ) {
            local.runProcess = false;
            local.fnResults = {status: 400, message: "Error! Incomplete or invalid data."};
        }

        if ( runProcess ) {
            local.qryParams = {rec_id: {cfsqltype: "cf_sql_numeric", value: "#arguments.recID#"}};
            local.deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM Articles WHERE rec_id = :rec_id";
            queryExecute(deleteSQL, qryParams, {datasource: "#application.datasource#", result: "deleteResult"});
            local.updateResult = updateProfile(arguments.agencyID);

            if ( deleteResult.recordcount && updateResult.recordcount ) {
                local.fnResults = {status: 200, message: "Record successfully removed."};
            } else {
                local.fnResults = {status: 400, message: "Error! Query failed."};
            }
        }
    } catch ( any e) {
        local.fnResults = {status: 400, message: "Error! Please contact your administrator"};
    }

    return fnResults;
}
```

Here is example of the function `updateProfile`:

```
public struct function updateAgencyProfile(required string storeID) {
    try {
        local.qryParams = {
            storeID: {cfsqltype: "cf_sql_numeric", value: "#arguments.storeID#"},
            user_id: client.userid
        };

        local.Profile_SQL = "
            UPDATE profile
            SET last_update = getDate(),
                user_id = :user_id
            WHERE store_id = :storeID
        ";

        queryExecute(Profile_SQL, qryParams, {datasource: "#application.datasource#", result: "updateResult"});

        return updateResult;
    } catch ( any e) {
        return {status: 400};
    }
}
```

As you can see in my example above delete query is executed first and right after I call public function `updateProfile` that will update profile table and return query result. I used this block of code to check if both queries are executed successfully:

```
if ( deleteResult.recordcount && updateResult.recordcount ) {
    local.fnResults = {status: 200, message: "Record successfully removed."};
} else {
    local.fnResults = {status: 400, message: "Error! Query failed."};
}
```

I'm wondering if that is necessary or I can let try catch block to detect any errors in this function? Also, is this a good fit for stored procedure? I have other functions that will need to call `updateProfile` to update the records. If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Your error handling is okay but your process would work better using [database transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). You did not mention the DBMS you are using but I assume it supports this. In ColdFusion you handle transactions by using [cftransaction (or transaction in cfscript)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-t/cftransaction.html).

Comment: @Miguel-F I use Sybase database for this project. Do you have some basic example on how to user transaction with queryEexecute and another function call? Thank you.

Comment: In addition to transactions, having two try/catch statements serves little purpose IMO.  Since it looks like `updateAgencyProfile()` is always called from another function, I'd drop the extra try/catch, let the error bubble up the calling function and handle it there.  Also, it's usually best to pass in any values needed by the function as arguments, instead of referencing external scopes directly: `user_id: client.userid`.

Comment: In addition, is there a specific reason the function only returns success if `delete.recordCount` <> 0? Typically, you wouldn't care if the record was already deleted. Just execute the query and move on.

Comment: @Ageax I revised that piece and it's not checking record count any more. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I would suggest not deleting records but setting a "void" bit flag. Restoring from backups for a bunch of accidentally deleted records is much more difficult than simply updating a void flag back to 0. Also, I could make a call to `deleteComment(1[or whatever],1[thru n])` and delete all of your comments for any given store. Make sure to do some validation before allowing that function to be called.

Comment: Also, if you're going to return a `status` in your object, you should be consistent and make a successful update be another struct with a `status` and `message` (and change your API to include any other object you intend to pass along. In `updateAgencyProfile()`, follow the same pattern you used in `deleteComment()`. Use a return object so that you always know the variables you pass out will be there. And rather than tell your user to contact their admin if they have a problem, log the error and tell them they had a problem that was forwarded to an admin.

Comment: And last, as was mentioned in another answer, you don't have to return a `result` variables from your `queryExecute()`. Just say `updateResult = queryExecute(....)`. Depending on how your datasource is set up, you may not even need a `queryOptions` struct.

Comment: @Shawn - I think he was using the "result" attribute because updates and deletes don't return a result set.